# How can I run two own functions with a delay?

Tags: jquery, delay

I have written two own functions, which I will now run automatically, but with an delay of 1500 ms.

When the counter reaches 7 the `preDial()` function is called. This is working so far.

When `preDial()` is done the system should wait 1500 ms and the call the `dialSequence()` function which contains an array and should execute the `each()` with all the gives values.

So how can I call these two functions with that delay?

Here is my code so far:

```
var count = 0;
var IDs = [];
var red = '#CC1919';
var green = '#30944B';
var orange = '#FDCA39';

$('.glyphs').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    count ++;
    dataId = $(this).attr('data-id');
    dataIcon = $(this).attr('data-icon');
    IDs.push([count, dataId]);

    $('#glyph-' + dataId).css('border-color', red);
    $('a#glyphs-' + dataId).contents().unwrap();

    if (count == 7) {
        preDial();
        $(this).delay(1500).dialSequence();
    }
});

function preDial() {
    $('.chevron-active').fadeIn('slow');
    $('.chevron-active').fadeOut('slow');
    $('#status').delay(750).text('Dialing . . .').css('color', orange);
    $('#sg_dial_circle').delay(750).addClass('rotate_right');
}

function dialSequence(IDs) {
    console.log('here');
    $.each(IDs, function(index, value) {
        console.log(value);
        $('.chevron-active.chevron-0' + index).delay(index * 1000).fadeIn('slow');
        $('.line-0' + index).delay(index * 1000).addClass('line-red');
    });
}
```

Thanks

kay899

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
setTimeout(function(){ 
    dialSequence(IDs);
}, 1500);
```

it's better to do without jQuery, and you forgot to pass IDs to function